# Passing an array as a parameter to a method

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my half done program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sclad {

public static void vavediMasiv(int col[], double cenaE[], double cenaD[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 1; i < col.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Molq vuvedete kolichestvoto ot produkt nomer " + i);
        col[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Kolichestvoto na produkta zadadeno kato: " + col[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < cenaE.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Molq vuvedete cenata na edro na produkt nomer " + i);
        cenaE[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cenata na produkta na edro zadadeno kato: " + cenaE[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < cenaD.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Molq vuvedete cenata na drebno na produkt " + i);
        cenaD[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cenata na produkta na drebno zadadeno kato: " + cenaD[i]);
    }

}
public static void calcPechalba(){
    for (int i = 1; i < col.length; i++)
        System.out.println("KUR");
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Vavedete broi na stokite prisustvashti v sklada...");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Vie izbrahte " + m + " za kolichestvo na stokite.");

    int col[] = new int[m+1];
    double cenaE[] = new double[m+1];
    double cenaD[] = new double[m+1];
    vavediMasiv(col[m+1], cenaE[m+1], cenaD[m+1]); // I GET AN ERROR HERE SAYING The method vavediMasiv(int[], double[], double[]) in the type Sclad is not applicable for the arguments (int, double, double)
}
}
```

I have commented the problematic part. I don't get why doesn't it accept as parameters. I have tried everything but it still won't accept the arrays. What can I do to fix this up or at least to compromise it and do it another way?

Comment: Pass array not some element of specified index

Answer (score 3):

You're passing it int and double values. To pass it the int and double arrays you need to do this:

```
vavediMasiv(col, cenaE, cenaD);
```

For example, here you're passing it the m+1 element of the cenaD array, and not the array itself.

```
cenaD[m+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

See... You have defined

```
public static void vavediMasiv(int col[], double cenaE[], double cenaD[]) // expecting and accepting whole arrays as arguments.
```

and you are using :

```
 vavediMasiv(col[m+1], cenaE[m+1], cenaD[m+1]); // you are passing individual values of arrays instead of whole array.
```

You have to use :

```
vavediMasiv(col, cenaE, cenaD);
```

Answer (score 0):

ou should pass the whole objects

```
vavediMasiv(col, cenaE, cenaD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing values in the array and not the actual array. That's why you are getting the error `int cant be converted to int[]` because `col[m +1]` is an `int` value in the `col` array. Same with the other two arrays.

```
vavediMasiv(col[m+1], cenaE[m+1], cenaD[m+1])
```

all the above are values *in* the array. You want

```
vavediMasiv(col, cenaE, cenaD);
```

You also might want to pass an array to this method also, to get rid of this error

```
public static void calcPechalba(int[] col){    <------
    for (int i = 1; i < col.length; i++)
        System.out.println("KUR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an (`int` `double` `double`) parameters to a method which signature says it accepts arrays of (`int` `double` `double`).

Looking to your source code, you merely need to change the

```
  vavediMasiv(col[m+1], cenaE[m+1], cenaD[m+1]);
```

call to:

```
  vavediMasiv(col, cenaE, cenaD);
```

You should also note that the below method won't compile since there is no local variable `col`:

```
public static void calcPechalba(){
   for (int i = 1; i < col.length; i++)
    System.out.println("KUR");
   }
```

Sorry but I can't understand your methods logical flow to give a better shot.

BR.

Answer (score 0):

Your method vavediMasiv(int col[], double cenaE[], double cenaD[]) is expecting three arguments of type int array, double array and double array. While you are passing int, double and double as arguments. That's why it is giving error.